# Value Error: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas Data Frames

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask, deployment

I have built a basic Linear Regression model on the Boston house price data set and deployed it using flask. Now when I go to the home page where I have to enter the values of features and click on predict to get a prediction, I get an error saying:-

```
ValueError: Specifying the columns using strings is only supported for pandas DataFrames
```

I was not getting this error when I ran my model in my IDE and it was predicting fine. But when I deployed my model using flask, and gave the feature values, it is giving me the error!! Any help would be appreciated. Below is my flask code:-

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify, request
import pickle

#Create Flask app
app = Flask(__name__)

#load the pickle file
model = pickle.load(open('model.pkl', 'rb'))

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')

#methods = post coz we are receive values of features

@app.route('/predict', methods = ['POST'])
def predict():
    float_features = [float(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    features = [np.array(float_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(features)

    return render_template('index.html', prediction_text = 'the price of the house is 
    '.format(prediction))

    if __name__ == '__main__':
       app.run(debug = True)
```

This is my HTML code:-

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<!--From https://codepen.io/frytyler/pen/EGdtg-->
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>ML API</title>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arimo' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind:300' 
rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Open+Sans+Condensed:300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', 
filename='css/style.css') }}">

</head>

<body>
 <div class="login">
  <h1>Predict Pricing Analysis</h1>

 <!-- Main Input For Receiving Query to our ML -->
<form action="{{ url_for('predict')}}"method="post">
    
    <input type="text" name="CRIM" placeholder="crim" 
    required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="NOX" placeholder="nox" required="required" 
    />
    <input type="text" name="RM" placeholder="rm" required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="AGE" placeholder="age" required="required" 
    />
    <input type="text" name="DIS" placeholder="dis" required="required" 
    />
    <input type="text" name="TAX" placeholder="tax" required="required" 
    />
    <input type="text" name="B" placeholder="b" required="required" />
    <input type="text" name="LSTAT" placeholder="lstat" 
    required="required" />


    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn- 
    large">Predict</button>
     </form>

  <br>
  <br>
      {{ prediction_text }}

  </div>
```

EDIT: I am using `Pipelines` and `ColumnTransformer` in my model which might be the problem but I'm not sure.